# Start a bounty still available after answer has been accepted.

Tags: support, bounty

[Fastest way to level up in Modern Warfare 2 / Black Ops](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/659/fastest-way-to-level-up-in-modern-warfare-2)

this question has been closed but I can still start a bounty.  Is this a feature or a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a feature of the [new bounty system](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/). It's been dissociated from acceptance, so the fact a question has an accepted answer is now irrelevant.

To award a bounty, click on the icon below the upvote and downvote arrow:

[image: The button below the upvote and downvote arrow, pointed by sad-looking stock arrows instead of freehanded circles.]

#### [» Read more about the bounty system.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/)

Comment: ok cool.  That's actually kinda useful :D

Comment: @Mechko: You can also start a bounty on other users' questions now, which is especially useful if you think the accepted answer is not entirely correct. Also you can award someone who put a lot of effort into an answer with some rep although you first didn't intend to

Comment: We just updated the FAQ to better explain this as well.